# Unable to compile the kernel module

Tags: kernel

I am trying to build a simple kernel in ubuntu,following are the errors getting while doing this.

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-52-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic'
make[1]: Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-52-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My Make file:

```
obj-m := module1.o 
KERNEL = $(shell uname -r)
all: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KERNEL)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KERNEL)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Can anybody help me out.

Note: I have already downloaded the kernel source code

Comment: HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic'
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-53-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Hi I have updated the make file as you told,and I am getting above errors

Answer (score 1):

You should set PWD variable in your Makefile before using it. E.g.

```
PWD = $(shell pwd)
```

**UPDATE**:
Also, your Makefile mix lines for two modes: KBuild mode (`obj-m := module1.o`) and common makefile mode(all other lines). Your should either distinguish modes(using `if`) or use two different files for two modes:

Makefile:

```
KERNEL = $(shell uname -r)
PWD = $(shell pwd)
all: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KERNEL)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KERNEL)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Kbuild:

```
obj-m := module1.o
```

Comment: Yes,I did that but still issue is occuring.How to get riddoff this issue,please help me out.