# Linux modules version error "Invalid module format"

Tags: linux, module, kernel, insmod

I made Linux external module and because my module need Linux kernel symbol,

I set the Modversion config and make it.(also did make modules_install)

My module was made exactly in lib/modules/(my linux)/extra/

But when I insert my module, shell prints error message

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module oxen_aggregator_module.ko: Invalid module format
```

This is dmesg contents

```
[  341.458351] oxen_aggregator_module: version magic '3.17.8-gentoo-r1 SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '3.17.8-gentoo-r1 SMP mod_unload '
```

But I need modversions flag because if I didn't set that flag, Module.symvers have just 0x00000000 addresses.

Could you help me? How can I solve?

My Make file

```
SRCS    = oxen_aggregator_module.c
OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

obj-m += $(OBJS)

KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS={/usr/src/linux-$(shell unamr -r)/Module.symvers}
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules_install
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
    $(RM) Module.markers modules.order
```

Comment: Usually, after changing versioning, whole kernel should be rebuilt (`make`, `make modules_install`, `make install` in the top-source directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did the same, but not solved. any other resolutions?

Comment: Split Makefile as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30332639/3440745 and remove KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS directive: kernel's `Module.symvers` file is used automatically. Then, after cleanup your module's directory, try to rebuild the module. By the way, your module is **not** placed in the kernel tree, is it?

Comment: Yes, My module is not placed in the kernel tree, but I need to use kernel function, that's why I want to refer kernel's symbol table! @Tsyvarev

Comment: Again, KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS needs only to be used for symbols from other modules **outside of the kernel**. You need not special means for use symbols from the kernel core and modules supplied with it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for explanation. I removed KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS, but problem is not solved...Always prints 'Invalid module format".. I think this problem occurred because of mode-version config. But I'm afraid that I can't refer to exported kernel symbol.(I already asked about these problem.) You said it's default to refer to kernel symbols from my module, but I couldn't before,, That's why I used KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS keyword and Modeversioning config. Could I need to turn off 'modversioning' configuration?  and how can I solve my problem? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to load module into kernel, for which it(module) hasn't be built. Or you build module for one kernel, but use KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS with `Module.symvers` file, created for another kernel.

If you need to use KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS with *kernel's* `Module.symvers file`, then it is definitely mess with different kernels somewhere.

Comment: So, how can I insert my module in the kernel tree from outer to use exported kernel symbol? or are there any explanation about external module programming ? Thank you

Comment: Just compile module, using Makefile without KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS. Set of kernel's symbols, available for outer modules, doesn't depend from modversion config.

Comment: [241282.009958] ch34x: version magic '4.4.35-v7 SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 ' should be '4.4.35_ecoo_81080868 SMP mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8 '